# How do I fix this problem where my "delete_at" dosen't work on numbers above 20 (or 20)?

Tags: ruby, sorting

The problem I have is that the "delete_at" method dosen't remove numbers over 20. Why I think it's especially over 20 is because of the troubleshooting I did below. I'm trying to make a sorting algorithm that sort an array of numbers from smallest to biggest. I want to do it without premade methods.

## What my code look like

```
unsorted_list = [20, 21, 40, 10, 18, -20, 100]
sorted_list = []

def index_of_smallest(array)
    i = 0
    small = array[0]
    while i < array.length
        if array[i] < small
            small = i
        end
        i += 1
    end
    return small
end

while unsorted_list.length > 0
    sorted_list << unsorted_list.delete_at(index_of_smallest(unsorted_list))
end
```

### TroubleShooting

```
    unsorted_list = [20, 21, 40, 10, 18, -20, 100]
sorted_list = []

def index_of_smallest(array)
    i = 0
    small = array[0]
    while i < array.length
        if array[i] < small
            small = i
        end
        i += 1
    end
    return small
end
puts "Before: #{unsorted_list.length}"

unsorted_list.delete_at(index_of_smallest(unsorted_list))

puts "After: #{unsorted_list.length}"

puts "--------------------------------------------------------------"

puts "Before: #{unsorted_list.length}"

unsorted_list.delete_at(index_of_smallest(unsorted_list))

puts "After: #{unsorted_list.length}"

puts "--------------------------------------------------------------"

puts "Before: #{unsorted_list.length}"

unsorted_list.delete_at(index_of_smallest(unsorted_list))

puts "After: #{unsorted_list.length}"

puts "--------------------------------------------------------------"

puts "Before: #{unsorted_list.length}"

unsorted_list.delete_at(index_of_smallest(unsorted_list))

puts "After: #{unsorted_list.length}"

puts "--------------------------------------------------------------"

puts "Before: #{unsorted_list.length}"

unsorted_list.delete_at(index_of_smallest(unsorted_list))

puts "After: #{unsorted_list.length}"

puts "--------------------------------------------------------------"

puts "Before: #{unsorted_list.length}"

unsorted_list.delete_at(index_of_smallest(unsorted_list))

puts "After: #{unsorted_list.length}"

puts "--------------------------------------------------------------"

puts "Before: #{unsorted_list.length}"

unsorted_list.delete_at(index_of_smallest(unsorted_list))

puts "After: #{unsorted_list.length}"

puts "--------------------------------------------------------------"

puts unsorted_list
```

#### Result

```
Before: 7
After: 6
--------------------------------------------------------------
Before: 6
After: 5
--------------------------------------------------------------
Before: 5
After: 4
--------------------------------------------------------------
Before: 4
After: 4
--------------------------------------------------------------
Before: 4
After: 4
--------------------------------------------------------------
Before: 4
After: 4
--------------------------------------------------------------
Before: 4
After: 4
--------------------------------------------------------------
20
21
40
100
```

#### Note

Sorry for bad format and layout are new to stackoverflow.

Comment: An error in your is `while i < array.length`. It should be `while i < (array.length-1)`. Also, it's not the "way of choice" of coding in Ruby but you'll learn the good way some day.

Answer (score 1):

`small` in  your code is supposed to be the *position* of the smallest element, not the element itself.

So change the initialization of small from...

```
small = array[0]
```

to...

```
small = 0
```

And change the comparison from...

```
    if array[i] < small
```

to...

```
    if array[i] < array[small]
```

Answer (score 1):

The method 'deleted_at' is working properly as below.

```
> 2.4.1 :007 > arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]  => [0,
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
> 21, 22] 
> 2.4.1 :008 > arr.delete_at(22)  => 22 
> 2.4.1 :009 > arr  => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21] 
> 2.4.1 :010 >
```

There is an issue with your code. Please go with each stage(mentioned in below code), you can find at stage 3 we are trying to sort unsorted_list which is already sorted.Hence the value of small from `index_of_smallest` is `nil` from stage 3. We need to merge `sorted_list + unsorted_list` after stage 2 and you will get the sorted array.
Please refere below code for better understanding:

```
unsorted_list = [20, 21, 40, 10, 18, -20, 100]
# As lenght of unsorted_list is going to change every time after deleting element
unsorted_list_length = unsorted_list.length
sorted_list = []

def index_of_smallest(array)
  i = 0
  small = array[i]
  #checking array is already sorted or not??
  small_element_found = false 
  while i < array.length
    p "array[i] < small-----#{array[i]} < #{small}--#{array[i] < small}"
    if array[i] < small
      small = i
      small_element_found = true
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return [small,small_element_found]
end

j = 0
while j < unsorted_list_length
  puts "******STAGE #{j}******"
  puts "unsorted_list------#{unsorted_list}"

  small_ele_index, arr_sorted = index_of_smallest(unsorted_list)
  sorted_list << unsorted_list.delete_at(small_ele_index) if arr_sorted
  puts "sorted_list------#{sorted_list}"

  j += 1
end

puts "Final Sorted List----------#{sorted_list + unsorted_list}"
```